# Setting up C++ with VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up VS Code in Windows 10 for making C++ programs by following [this official tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). However, despite following all of the steps, when I have a completed source code open in VS Code and go to "run build task" no menus open and it simply says "Fetching building tasks..." indefinitely. I did find an extension called Code Runner which seems to work and builds executables for me but I'd still like to get the default functionality working too.

Comment: if you're not a c++ expert I'd recommend using visual studio instead, its much easier to setup

Comment: You have to create a build talk first.